# Unity 5 2D make coins move towards player

Tags: 2d, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have written a script that I have attached to `Player` which upon collecting a `Magnet` `Power-Up`, finds all the active `GameObjects` with a tag `Treasure` and makes them follow `Player`.

The thing is that I want all the active `Treasure` `GameObjects` not to only follow but actually go towards and collide with the `Player` so that points are collected.

Below is my code so far, any help is appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TreasureFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] treasures;
    public bool magnetPowerUpEnabled = false;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
     if (col.CompareTag("Magnetpowerup"))
        {
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            magnetPowerUpEnabled = true;

        }
    }

        // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (magnetPowerUpEnabled)
        {
            treasures = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Treasure");
            foreach (var treasure in treasures)
            {
                treasure.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(treasure.transform.position, transform.position, 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does move objects taged Treasure towards the player. What exactly are you having trouble with ? Collecting the treasure once it has collided with the player or  what? Also try increasing the speed to more than 1.0f

Comment: Could you please clarify this part? `actually go towards and collide with the Player`

Comment: @UriPopov thank you, after increasing the speed it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ensure the treasure moves faster than the player so it can catch up for starters. Then have a small script either on the treasure or the player which checks for onTriggerEnter calls. When the treasure touches the player then fire off a function destroying or disabling it and increase the players score however is appropriate.